# Docker swarm cant increase network pool size

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm creating swarm with

```
docker swarm init --default-addr-pool-mask-length 16 --advertise-addr 10.242.233.175:2377
```

But when i inspect swarm it shows `SubnetSize: 24` not 16 as i specified

```
docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
 Containers: 9
  Running: 6
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 271
 Server Version: 20.10.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: ncw2gbs63skixzzcnddzp44c2
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: ueexyydqt7o1py296iwhfi8bg
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
...
```

How to increase address pool for swarm services?